# how to get drop down from athother table in rails using rails_admin gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

`user` model has one_to_many association between `project` and  `user` model has one to many association between `incharge_project`. i am using `rails_admin` gem for creation of user. now i want to get drop down of all project in  `incharge_project` while creation user in rails_admin. how can i this with rails admin>

`incharge_project` has `user_id` and `project_id` column.

here is my code -

rails_admin.rb

```
   config.model 'User' do
     field :name
     field :email
     field :password
     field :password_confirmation
     field :incharge_projects
   end
```

Comment: If you are creating a user, that user doesn't have an id yet. How do you want to get all associated incharge_projects to a user that is not created yet?

Comment: @AleksanderLopez what is the effective solution to resolve such problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, something like this should do the job:

```rb
    permit_params incharge_project_ids: []

    form do |f|
      f.semantic_errors
      f.input :name
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
      f.input :incharge_project_ids, as: :select, collection: Project.all.pluck(:name, :id)
      f.actions
    end
```

Make sure that your User model has this:

```rb
  has_many :projects, through: :incharge_projects
  has_many :incharge_projects
```